# How to use JSON/XML to pass data to a form using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

I am automating a registration form that has various fields such as Name, Email, Phone etc. and I wish to pass data to the form without using Excel or CSV files, and I want to use JSON/XML instead. Now I have no clue how to achieve that, would be very helpful if someone can tell me what dependencies I need to use and how do I go about it.

Comment: What you had tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to read the `JSON` and pass the data to scripts but we don't know your `JSON` so I am assuming the `JSON` in below format.

**JSON**:

```
{
    "name":"Nandan",
    "email":"nandan@gmail.com",
    "phone":1234567890
 }
```

**Maven dependency**:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.json</groupId>
     <artifactId>json</artifactId>
     <version>20160212</version>
 </dependency>
```

**Imports**:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

**Read and get data from JSON**:

```
String jsonDataAsString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Sample.json")));
         
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonDataAsString);
System.out.println(jsonData.get("name"));
System.out.println(jsonData.get("email"));
System.out.println(jsonData.get("phone"));
```

**Output**:

```
Nandan
nandan@gmail.com
1234567890
```